# error passing a std::function vs a function pointer as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, std-function

I have the following piece of code, in which I declare 2 functions that take a function as a parameter (one by using `std::function`, the other one by using a pointer to a function). The function taken as a parameter has to have the prototype `std::complex<double>(const std::complex<double>&`). An example of such a parameter is `std::sqrt` in C++11, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt . Now, I have absolutely no clue why the function that takes a pointer-to-function works (i.e. `g_of_ten`), whereas the other one, that takes a `std::function` as a parameter, doesn't (i.e. `f_of_ten`). If I uncomment the line

```
//cout << f_of_ten(std::sqrt) << endl; // ERROR here!!!
```

I get the error

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'f_of_ten'
        cout << f_of_ten(std::sqrt) << endl; // ERROR here!!!
                ^~~~~~~~
    /Users/vlad/minimal.cpp:10:6: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'sqrt' matching 'std::function<cplx (const cplx &)> &' for 1st argument
    cplx f_of_ten(std::function<cplx(const cplx &)>& x)
     ^
    1 error generated.
```

I am completely puzzled why this is happening, I though that `std::function` is really a wrapper for all kinds of functors (INCLUDING standard functions). Any help is more than welcome!
Below is the code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using cplx = complex<double>; // to save some typing

cplx f_of_ten(std::function<cplx(const cplx &)> x) // the problematic one
{
    return x(10);
}

cplx g_of_ten(cplx(*x)(const cplx &)) // this works
{
    return (*x)(10);
}


int main()
{
    //cout << f_of_ten(std::sqrt) << endl; // compile ERROR here!!!
    cout << g_of_ten(std::sqrt) << endl;
}
```

PS: I, of course, also tried `cout << f_of_ten(&std::sqrt) << endl;`, same story, compile time error.

@Yakk,

this works fine:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

using cplx = std::complex<double>; // to save some typing

cplx f_of_ten(std::function<cplx(const cplx &)> x) // the problematic one
{
    return x(10);
}

cplx g_of_ten(cplx(*x)(const cplx &)) // this works
{
    return (*x)(10);
}


int main()
{
    //cout << f_of_ten(std::sqrt<double>) << endl; // compile ERROR here!!!
    std::cout << g_of_ten(std::sqrt) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that template argument deduction will not instantiate templates to find a match so you need to use `std::sqrt<double>`

Comment: Ok, I actually just found this exactly now :) Thanks anyway, that was the issue indeed.

Comment: @PeterT there is no guarantee that `std::sqrt` exists as a `template` function, or that there is one, or that its first `template` argument is the type of its argument.

Comment: @Yakk he's using this function http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt which is a template function

Comment: @Yakk, at least that's what they say in the standard C++11, that `std::sqrt` is templated for complex numbers.

Comment: But why does the pointer version work then?

Comment: @vsoftco because overload resolution is different from template argument deduction in this regard

Comment: The important thing here is that `std::function`'s constructor's type signature accepts an arbitrary type. This is why `std::sqrt` cannot be resolved when used to initialize a `std::function`. The fact that `std::sqrt` is templated is not relevant. There are also three overloads for `std::sqrt` when you include `<cmath>` for example, and that would also cause the same error.

Comment: @Brian Ok, thanks, I got this and it makes sense, however, why can the pointer version resolve the underlying type `T` of `std::complex<T>`?.

Comment: @vsoftco, this is done by template parameter deduction. Only when `T = double` does the type of the parameter `x` match the type of the argument.

Comment: @Brian, thanks for your patience :) What I don't get is why the pointer version works, that is, why it can always somehow unwrap the type from template, whereas the `std::function` fails. It now seems that for this templates inside `std::function`, it is better to use function pointers, at least that's my understanding now.

Comment: @vsoftco, because `std::function<R(T...)>` doesn't "know" that it can only be constructed from a function iff the function has type `R(T...)`. The constructor accepts an arbitrary type, and then somewhere down the line you get a compilation error.

Comment: I was wrong: one such is guraranteed to exist.  But any number of others can exist, including a `valarray` one.  Explicitly instantiating `template` parameters to `std` functions is bad practice.

Comment: Ok, then maybe my question should be reformulated: I am writing an Eigen matrix function that takes a complex<double> `Matrix` as a parameter and applies a transformation componentwise on all of its elements, mapping complex to complex, the matrix taken by reference. Now, how would you write such a generic function? (just assume the matrix is a type called `Matrix`) I'd like to use `f` for the functor that is applied to each matrix entry, and would also like to be able to use the standard C++ library functions as possible functors, i.e. `std::sqrt` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bad idea, see comments and edit!**

The `std::sqrt` for complex numbers is a template, if you use `std::sqrt<double>` your code works.

Not to sure why the g... variant works thou.

**Edit to salvage this answer:**

You can use a lambda to select the correct `sqrt` like

```
std::cout << f_of_ten([](cplx x){return std::sqrt(x);}) << std::endl;
```

Now template argument deduction and overload resolution will take place, select the right `sqrt` and pack it in the lambda which binds to `std::function`.

Comment: Yeah exactly, if the `std::function` cannot deduce the `T`, why can the pointer version do that?

Comment: @vsoftco `#include <valarray>` and the above fails, as there is **no** guarantee that there is exactly one `template<class T>sqrt` function, the above is fragile and can break at any time for no reason.

Comment: @Yakk Welp, then my answer is garbage, would delete. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Yakk, see my updated code, it works fine even with `valarray` included

Comment: @vsoftco welcome to working with things on the edge of legality: that is why the answer is brittle (one compiler works, another does not), so a bad idea even if it works in your current environment.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one overload of `std::sqrt` and your code does not know how to determine which one you want.

Try:

```
typedef cplx(*complex_function)(const cplx &);

std::cout << f_of_ten( complex_function( std::sqrt ) ) << std::endl;
```